# eCharts4r - Axis ticks/text fontSize

Tags: r, echarts4r

Is it possible to alter the font size of the y- and x-axis ticks?

I have looked through the documentation and can't find anything that works.

reprex:

```
library(lubridate)
library(echarts4r)

df <- data.frame(
  Date = dmy("01/01/2020","01/02/2020","01/03/2020","01/04/2020","01/06/2020"),
  Temperature = c(10, 2, 4, 5, 1),
  Phosphate = c(4, 1, 2, 5, 6)
)

df |> 
  e_charts(Date) |> 
  e_bar(Phosphate, y_index = 1) |>
  e_line(Temperature) |>
  e_text_style(fontSize = 24)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to set the `fontSize` via the `e_axis` functions.
As I get it from the docs `e_text_style` sets the global font style, which however seems to have no effect on the tick labels except for the first label where instead of `Jan` the year is shown. The font size of this label has to be set via `e_text_style`. Not sure whether I missed something.

```r
library(lubridate)
library(echarts4r)

df <- data.frame(
  Date = dmy("01/01/2020", "01/02/2020", "01/03/2020", "01/04/2020", "01/06/2020"),
  Temperature = c(10, 2, 4, 5, 1),
  Phosphate = c(4, 1, 2, 5, 6)
)

df |>
  e_charts(Date) |>
  e_bar(Phosphate, y_index = 1) |>
  e_line(Temperature) |>
  e_x_axis(
    axisLabel = list(
      fontSize = 24,
      color = "red"
    )
  ) |> 
  e_y_axis(
    axisLabel = list(
      fontSize = 24,
      color = "green"
    )
  ) |> 
  e_y_axis(
    index = 1,
    axisLabel = list(
      fontSize = 24,
      color = "blue"
    )
  ) |> 
  e_text_style(
    fontSize = 24  
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you! Through your answer I found that the problem was happening when using a suffix. The fontSize won't apply when a suffix is being used, how weird.